# How to raise INotifyPropertyChanged from a view-model object on the correct thread in C++/winrt

Tags: c++-winrt

I have a non-gui object that reads voltage and current from a hardware device. When these values change the object needs to change these properties and raise a INotifyPropertyChanged event.

There is a struct winrt::resume_foreground, but that can be used to switch to the correct thread, but the constructor needs a reference to a GUI object (in the sample code).

What is the best method to capture the correct dispatcher object that should be used?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a GUI to switch to a particular thread. Instead, you can capture the calling context on entry, and switch to it at any time. This is explained under [Programming with thread affinity in mind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency#programming-with-thread-affinity-in-mind), alongside a code example:

```cpp
IAsyncAction DoWorkAsync(TextBlock textblock)
{
    winrt::apartment_context ui_thread; // Capture calling context.

    co_await winrt::resume_background();
    // Do compute-bound work here.

    co_await ui_thread; // Switch back to calling context.

    textblock.Text(L"Done!"); // Ok if we really were called from the UI thread.
}
```

Alternatively, if you have access to a [DependencyObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject), you can use its [Dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.dispatcher) property for use with the `winrt::resume_foreground` class:

```cpp
IAsyncAction DoWorkAsync(DependencyObject targetObject)
{
    co_await winrt::resume_background();
    // Do compute-bound work here.

    co_await winrt::resume_foreground(targetObject.Dispatcher());

    // Raise INotifyPropertyChanged event.
}
```

Likewise, you can invoke the [CoreDispatcher.RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync) method from your coroutine, to raise the [PropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged) event on the thread owning the respective `DependencyObject`:

```cpp
IAsyncAction DoWorkAsync(DependencyObject targetObject)
{
    co_await winrt::resume_background();
    // Do compute-bound work here.

    co_await targetObject.Dispatcher().RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal,
                                                [=]()
    {
        // Raise event
    });

    // Continue work
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have 2 functions: void Start() and void Stop(). Start will start the monitoring process and Stop will be called just before the app ends. Once in a while a need to raise the property change event from the non-gui object. It seems that the best solution is to capture the context in the Start() method in a member variable and switch to it in my RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged event.

Comment: @VictorDerks: In order to support a dependency property, the object defining it must be a [DependencyObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject). So somewhere in your code, there is a `DependencyObject` you can use to access its `Dispatcher()` property, either for use with the `resume_foreground` class, or to invoke its [RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync) method. Both of those solutions are more robust than storing the current thread context. The latter can change as you update your code.